How to effeciently iterate of rows in Pandas without iterrows()
I know that you can use the .iterrows() function to grab each row individually, but I have a huge Dataframe and everything I've read says that the .iterrows() function is very slow. How can I more elegantly iterate over all rows individually? I need to grab several datapoints from each row, so I can't do it by column name. I also need to grab multiple datapoints from each column (essentially if value in column A has a certain value, do something with value in column B.).
Effectively I'd like to do something like:
names = []
for row in df.rows():
    if row["income"] > 50000:
        names.append(row["name"])

I got this to work with iterrows(), but it's very slow. Someone mentioned in another post something about using the iterrows() function only as a last resort, but offered no explicit examples of alternatives.

For logical filtering, no need to iterate through rows: names = df[df["income"] > 50000]["name"].to_list()

Thank you so much! What sort of logic is this called? I was hoping to find something like this, but I couldn't find it anywhere. What would I have to search to find this sort of logic?

boolean indexing

Thank you both! You solved all my problems with this project in two short answers!
